# Do we use papers (as flat material, not as newspapers) in British English?

Tags: word-usage, british-english

On [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/paper) web site under British English tab, there is examples on "paper" word. on of these examples use "papers" word.

> "paper" in British English: thin, flat material made from crushed wood or cloth, used for writing, printing, or drawing on.
>
> Example: He rifled through the **papers** on the desk, but couldn't find the photographs.

Do we use *papers* (as flat material, not as newspapers) in British English?

When we say: give me the paper. what does this mean in British English? one or more than one?

Comment: *Papers* can just mean *documents*, and this may be the case here.

Comment: @Mick , thank you, Do we use papers (as flat material, not as newspapers) in British English?

Comment: *Paper* is the mass noun. *Papers* means a collection of documents such as letters, invoices, stuff you have written yourself, etc. *Paperwork* is another term for this, although it means documents that have to be dealt with in some way.

Comment: Note that paper is a substance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Paper** can be used as both a singular and collective noun.

Therefore, **paper** can refer to both a single sheet of paper as well as multiple sheets of paper.

**Papers** emphasizes multiple sheets of paper. It makes clear that the person wishes to be handed multiple sheets of paper, often ones that are meant to be together.

When speaking of a newspaper, you would simply use **paper**.

Answer (score 1):

Some aspects I'd like to consider:

- We generally use "paper" or "papers" to refer to a piece of writing containing some information. For instance, if you go to an airport, the staff may ask: "Could you give me your papers, please?". In this case, "papers" could be a passport, some work permission, or another kind of document.
- The noun "paper" can also be used as a synonym for "newspaper" (e.g. He bought a paper/newspaper)
  If "paper" in your sentence means material (e.g. the house is made of paper), it's an uncountable noun.
- Conversely, if you want to talk about the flat object with which we usually write, I believe the appropriate term is "a sheet of paper". Now, it's countable. Therefore, you could say something like: "I required ten sheets of paper to make my essay".

[image]

This is a sheet of paper.